# Finding overlapping and gaps between two numbers in a list

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures

I have a list of of objects that look like this:

```
public class Products
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public decimal MinimumPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal MaximumPrice { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to perform two types of validations on this list:

a) The values should not overlap (example of invalid input

Object1: MinimumPrice: 1 - MaximumPrice: 5

Object2: MinimumPrice: 3 - MaximumPrice: 6

It would be valid if the second object was MinimumPrice: 6 - MaximumPrice: 7

b) The second validation should be that there will be no gaps between the objects:

Using the above example, if Object2 was MinimumPrice: 8 - MaximumPrice: 9  , it would be invalid since there would be a gap between 6 and 7.

What would be the best way to perform these validations?

Comment: i dont understand your samples...

Comment: Sort them by minimum then maximum, then compare each object with the next one, to see if they are overlapping or there are gaps.

Comment: Only one comparison is needed : Object1.MaximumPrice == Object2.MinimumPrice   You are using decimal where there could be a very tiny overlap like 1.0E-12.  Is that an overlap?

Comment: @Knewit To apply these validation, the list of object must be fixed the order and no sort?

Comment: It seems like a linked-list with MaximumPrice linked with another MinimumPrice+1 until end of the list.

Comment: This is my definition of overlapping. https://helgesverre.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/overlapping.png All these cases are invalid in my scenario. The logic behind this is that no Product's MinimumPrice and MaximumPrice is allowed to be between the range of another Product's MinimumPrice and MaximumPrice. This is similar to Date periods overlapping but in my case I have to implement it with Min/Max numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first sort your products by `MinimumPrice` with [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8), then sort by `MaximumPrice` with [`ThenBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var sortedProducts = products
    .OrderBy(product => product.MinimumPrice)
    .ThenBy(product => product.MaximumPrice);
```

Then you could make methods to check if two products overlap or have gaps in prices:

```
private static bool ProductsOverlap(Products x, Products y)
{
    return x.MinimumPrice < y.MaximumPrice && y.MinimumPrice < x.MaximumPrice;
}

private static bool ProductsHaveGaps(Products x, Products y)
{
    return y.MinimumPrice - x.MaximumPrice > 1;
}
```

And then you could [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8) the product pairs and check if [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) of the sorted products overlap or have gaps:

```
var overlapOrHaveGaps = sortedProducts
    .Zip(sortedProducts.Skip(1), (x, y) => (x, y))
    .Any(pair => ProductsOverlap(pair.x, pair.y) || ProductsHaveGaps(pair.x, pair.y));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Select` which little bit verbose lambda:

```
// Class definition
public class Range 
{
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public Range(int min, int max) => (Min, Max) = (min, max);
}

int prevMax = 0;
var gaps = ranges.OrderBy(r => r.Min).Select((r, i) =>
{
    // If index is 0 there's nothing to check.
    // First check is that previous Max is current Min, so
    // we don't have gaps.
    // Second is checking for overlapping.
    // Crucial for this is ordering.
    var noGapAndNoOverlap = i == 0 ? true : prevMax == r.Min && prevMax <= r.Min;
    prevMax = r.Max;
    return noGapAndNoOverlap;
})
// Now each elements is true or false, indicating that
// wether we do not have overlapping or gaps.
.All(i => i);
```